# Process multiple inputs with multiple equivalent commands (multiple thread pools) in GNU parallel

Tags: parallelism, gnu-parallel

I have a large dataset (>200k files) that I would like to process (convert files into another format). The algorithm is mostly single-threaded, so it would be natural to use parallel processing. However, I want to do an unusual thing. Each file can be converted using one of two methods (CPU- and GPU-based), and I would like to utilize both CPU and GPU at the same time.

Speaking abstractly, I have two different commands (`foo` and `bar`), which are supposed to produce equivalent results. I would like to organize two thread pools with fixed capacity that would run up to N instances of `foo` and M instances of `bar` respectively, and process each input file with either of those pools depending on which one has free slots (determinism is not required or desired).

Is it possible to do something like that in GNU parallel or with any other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```bsh
gpus=2

find files |
  parallel -j +$gpus '{= $_ = slot() > '$gpus' ? "foo" : "bar" =}' {}
```

Less scary:

```bsh
  parallel -j +$gpus '{=
      if(slot() > '$gpus') {
        $_ = "foo"
      } else {
        $_ = "bar"
      }
    =}' {}
```

`-j +$gpus` Run one job per CPU thread + $gpus

`{= ... =}` Use perl code to set $_.

`slot()` Job slot number (1..cpu_threads+$gpus).

Comment: Thanks!
I forgot that parallel is perl-scriptable. Looks scary but does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

values=( a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
start=0

function foo()
{
        sleep 4
        echo "foo ${1}"
}

function bar()
{
        sleep 4
        echo "bar ${1}"
}

function baz()
{
        sleep 4
        echo "baz ${1}"
}

while [ ${#values[@]} -gt 0 ]
do 
        if [ ${#values[@]} -gt 0 ]
        then
                foo "${values[0]}" &
                values=("${values[@]:1}")
        fi

        if [ ${#values[@]} -gt 0 ]
        then
                bar "${values[0]}" &
                values=("${values[@]:1}")
        fi

        if [ ${#values[@]} -gt 0 ]
        then
                baz "${values[0]}" &
                values=("${values[@]:1}")
        fi

        wait
done
```

values `values=( a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)` you can replace by `values=$(ls -1)`

Comment: Interesting. But I'm not seeing any parallelization and it's not immediately obvious how to implement that short of copy-pasting. Let's say I want to launch up to 32 instances of `foo` simultaneously and up to 8 instances of `bar` simultaneously, how would I do that?

Comment: Inside loop as `for i in {1..32}; do ...; done` where `...` is "if" with foo and second one `for i in {1..8}` with "if" bar function, all process are going background, so it is pseudo parallelization, but works fine

Comment: Also this can be written as one liner ;) if you want, also... You can do "copy paste" version for shell (here bash)

Comment: Also as I think it should be possible to run foo and bar loops independent now main loop waiting for finish all background jobs

Comment: Ah, well, argumentless `wait` waits for all children. I see. This should superficially work, but doesn't really suit my problem because `foo` and `bar` have significantly different (and variable) performance. I'm afraid this won't be too efficient.